# Parse JSON { "key" : "value" } JQuery

Tags: jquery, json

I'm makeing autocomplete fetaure.

This is mine ajax - json - response, representing `"id":"name"` pairs:

```
// consloe:
Object {"14":"Mike","15":"John","23":"Drew","45":"Steve","52":"Andrew"}
```

which i get from:

```
while($row=$result->fetch_array()){
    $output[$row['user_id']] = $row['user'];
}
echo json_encode($output);
```

Im trying to make this `<div data-user="id">name</div>` for each of pair. But I can't handle it.. :/

```
var results = JSON.parse(data);
$(results).each(function(key, value) {
    $('#results').append('<div class="item">'+ value + '</div>');
})
```

Code above worked fine while I had only `name`s in json response (`$output[] = $row['user'];`).

But I need `user_id` to assign it into input value of chosen option.

This is what I've wright now:

```
console.log(results);
$(results).each(function(key, value) {
    console.log(key);
    console.log(value);
})

// console:
// Object {"14":"Mike","15":"John","23":"Drew","45":"Steve","52":"Andrew"}
// 0
// {"14":"Mike","15":"John","23":"Drew","45":"Steve","52":"Andrew"}
```

I'm totally confused

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fix your data structure to be more friendly

Array of objects where each object has the same property names is far more sensible ( and more common)

```
while($row=$result->fetch_array()){
    $output[] =array('id'=>$row['user_id'], 'user'=> $row['user']);
}
echo json_encode($output);
```

Will produce:

```
[{"id":"14","user":"Mike"},{"id":"15","user":"John"}.......]
```

Now when you iterate the array you have access to the same properties in each iteration. By using these property names it is much easier to read also.

```
$.each(data, function(arrayIndex, userObject){
   $('#results').append('<div data-user="' + userObject.id+'">'+ userObject.user + '</div>');
});
```

Also note that arrays are easier to filter and sort and there are lots of native methods for arrays to assist you.

You can also make the property names match your back end for simplicity of updates

Comment: I allready accepted Azim's answer, before you posted but still thank you for help. I'll use your solution. I shoulda been think about it insted of look for kinda workaround

Comment: well if this helps your situation more and you think would be better for future readers it is not inappropriate to switch selected answer

Answer (score 1):

Iterate through all properties of the object and create `div` with `id` and `value` and then append to `#results`.

```js
var json = { "14": "Mike", "15": "John", "23": "Drew", "45": "Steve", "52": "Andrew" };

for (var prop in json) {
   $('#results').append('<div id='+prop+'>'+json[prop]+'</div>');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="results"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

So this is example getting your key and value;

Check console for results: JsFiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/5hpr5bhm/

```
var data = {"14" :"Mike", "15" :"John", "23" :"Drew", "45" :"Steve", "52" :"Andrew"};

for (var key in data) {
    console.log("User " + data[key] + " is" + key); // "User john is 24"
}
```